# How fast did the interior of Venus warm up?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, astrophysics, atmospheric-science, planets

*Context:* The atmosphere of Venus wasn't always as warm as now: a few hundred million years ago it was much more habitable. I am interested in how fast the interior of the planet warmed up, after it's climate changed.

*Model:*
Venus is a uniform sphere with some heat conductivity $\alpha$, temperature distribution $f(r)$ at $t=0$. I am interested in how the temperature changes ie in $u(r,t)$.

---

## Setup

*Equation to solve:*$$\dot{u}=\alpha \nabla^2 u$$

*In spherical polars*:
$$\dot{u} = \alpha \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)$$

*Initial & Boundary conditions:*
$$u(r \leq R, t=0) = f(r)$$ and $$u(r=R,t \geq 0) = f(R)$$
(Ie planet has some initial temperature distribution straight after its outermost layers warmed up, we keep the outermost layers at fixed temperature $f(R)$.)

*Change of variables:* I change from $u$ to $v(r,t)=u(r,t)-\frac{r}{R}f(R)-\frac{R-r}{R}f(0)$, so IC satisfied by $v$: $$v(r \leq R,t=0)=f(r)-\frac{r}{R}f(R) = g(r)$$
BC satisfied by $v$:
$$v(r=R)=0$$
(and $v(r=0)$ will also be $0$ which is ideal).

---

## Solution

**Strategy:** separation of variables. Ie: $v(r,t) = T(t)\rho(r)$. Plug this into heat equation, obtain two ODEs:

### Temporal ODE

$$T'=-\lambda \alpha T$$
ie:
$$T = e^{-\lambda \alpha t}$$
(Will deal with the arbitrary multiplicative constant in the spatial part.)

### Spatial ODE

The equation we get after separating variables:

$$r\rho''+2\rho'+\lambda r \rho = 0$$

The allowable solution to this is:

$$\rho(r)=\frac{c_0}{\sqrt{\lambda}r}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}r)$$

(The other solution is with $\cos$ instad of $\sin$, but that goes to infinity as $r$ approaches $0$, so I don't use those.)

**BC requires that:**

$$\lambda=\frac{n^2\pi^2}{R^2}$$

**IC requires that:**

We find a linear combination of $\rho_n$s which sum to $g(r)$.

Rearrange spatial equation:

$$-\rho''-\frac{2}{r}\rho' = \lambda \rho$$

Recall that Sturm-Liouville operators have orthogonal eigenfunctions, we let's turn this into SL form by multiplying by $r^2$. Rearrange, get SL form:

$$-r^2\rho''-2r\rho'=-\frac{d}{dr}\left(r^2\frac{d}{dr}\rho\right) = \lambda r^2 \rho$$

Need normalized eigenfunctions, ie:

$$\int_0^R \rho(r,n)\rho(r,m) r^2 dr = \delta_{nm}$$

where $r^2$ has been included because it is the weight function. Arrive at:
$$c_0  = \frac{n\pi}{R}\sqrt{\frac{2}{R}}$$

To find the linear combination, I use the Green's function method. $\rho(r)$ is given by:

$$\rho(r)=\int_0^R G(r, \zeta)\zeta^2\rho(\zeta) d\zeta$$

where $\zeta^2$ is the weight function and

$$G(r, \zeta) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda_n}\rho_n(r)\rho_n(\zeta)$$

Rearrange to make it clearer that we have a weighted sum, get $\rho$:

$$\rho(r)=\sum_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_n}\int_0^R\rho_n(\zeta)\zeta^2g(\zeta)d\zeta\right)\rho_n(r)$$

### Unite results

Bring back $f$, put time dependence back in, transform back to $u$ by adding back what we subtracted from it:

$$u(r,t)=\sum_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda_n}\int_0^R\rho_n(\zeta)\zeta^2\left(f(\zeta)-\frac{\zeta}{R}f(R)\right) d \zeta \right)               
\rho_n(r) e^{-\lambda_n \alpha t} + \frac{r}{R}f(R)$$

---

## Checking

I would like to check what I have done above is numerically correct, with Python.

```
# Useful packages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
import scipy.integrate as integrate
```

Variables:

```
step=0.001
start=0+step
stop=4
r = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
r_xsi = np.arange(start, stop+step, step)
R=stop
```

Defining $\lambda_n$, $\rho_n$:

```
def LAMBDA(n,R=stop):
    return n**2*np.pi**2/(R**2)

def rho_func(r,n,R=stop):
    return (n*np.pi/R)*(2/R)**0.5*1/((LAMBDA(n)**0.5)*r)*np.sin((LAMBDA(n)**0.5)*r)
```

An example initial temperature distribution, $f(r)$:

```
def f(r,R=stop):
    return (np.exp((20*(r-0.95*R))/R)+np.cos(r/R)**2+1/(r+0.4))
```

Which transforms into, after changing variables:

```
def g(r, R=stop, f=f):
    return f(r) - r/R*f(R)
```

Define the max $n$ we are calculating, calculate $\lambda$s:

```
Nmax=50
ns=range(1, Nmax+1)
LAMBDAS=np.array([LAMBDA(n) for n in ns])
```

Calculate the integral which will be the weight in the sum:

```
integrals = np.array([res for res, error in [integrate.quad(lambda zeta: rho_func(zeta, n)*(zeta**2)*g(r=zeta, R=R), 0, R, limit=1000) for n in ns]])
```

Divide result of $n$th integration by $\lambda_n$, multiply by $\rho_n$, sum over $n$ just us our formula requires:

```
res = np.sum(np.stack([coeff*rho_func(r,n) for n, coeff in enumerate(1/LAMBDAS*integrals,1)]),axis=0)
```

Without taking into account the temporal variation, let's check if the initial condition (ie when $T(t=0)=1$ anyway) is satisfied:

```
plt.plot(r,f(r),label='f')
plt.plot(r,res+ r/R*f(R),label='Should be f')
plt.legend()
```

Which gives:

[image]

which is clearly wrong.

---

## Question

What am I doing wrong? Are the calculations wrong, or I am just implementing the checking in a wrong way, and the calculations are correct? I am curious.

Comment: Aside from not wanting to debug your code, why do you think the interior of Venus warmed up as a result of the atmosphere warming?

Comment: Nope, I don't; I still think it is an interesting equation to solve, I could apply it to other things, ie frozen droplets.

Comment: So I assume you think my math is correct, only the code is wrong.

Comment: (I have more confidence in the code than in my math, though.)

Comment: Ok, I discovered a mistake in the math.

Comment: Writing it down neatly, when done, I'll post it here.